# Is there a way to efficiently compile already preprocessed file with clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c-preprocessor, clang++

I got a preprocessed file with command: `clang++ -E test.cc > test.E`
Then I want to quickly compile it. To do it, I run `clang++ -### -c test.cc`, then I take all those flags and just replace input file name from `test.cc` to `test.E`.

But I wonder, if there are some redundant flags in output of `clang++ -###` for already preprocessed file, or may be there are some flags, that force clang to skip preprocessing or some other unnecessary steps.

The aim is to speed up the compilation of a **preprocessed** file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To speed-up compilation I need to replace the flag's "-x" argument to the proper language, like: "c" -> "cpp-output", "c++" -> "c++-cpp-output", etc.
In this case clang won't run preprocessing at all.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use *.i suffix for C files and *.ii for C++. clang will know to treat them as preprocessed even without the -x flag.